# Linq-to-SQL - how to concatenate two fields in a sub select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

The following Linq-to-SQL code does not return any customer results when I search for first name and last name, such as "Joe Smith". My syntax to concatenate `FirstName` and `LastName` is not correct - can you please help?

```
var searchText = "Joe Smith";

IQueryable<Customer> query = dc.Customer
                               .Where(cust => cust.Contact.Select(con => con.FirstName + " " + con.LastName).Contains(searchText));

var customers = query.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

Comment: Not 100% sure here, but I believe the `.Contains()` is case sensitive. I would use `.ToLower()` on both your `searchText` and concatenated field.

Comment: Thanks David for the response but that is not the problem. The name in the db is Joe Smith and if I pass in Joe Smith with the same case I get no results back. The code compiles fine, no errors, but does not execute as expected.

Comment: Is `Contact`  single object or a collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I absolutely appreciate the answers from the two contributors, they did not solve my specific need.

My solution... first get the CustomerIds from the Contacts table, then look up the customer records:

```
var customerIds = dc.Contact
.Where(c => (c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName).Contains(text))
                      .Select(c => c.CustomerId)
.Distinct()
.ToArray();

var customers = dc.Customer
.Where(c => customerIds.Contains(c.Id))
.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

as far I understand here is your solution

hope it will solve your problem.

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = dc.Customer.Where(cust =>new {fullName=cust.FirstName+" "+cust.LastName}.fullName.Contains(searchText));

var customers = query.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

here is the edited solution please check it out and let me know

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = dc.Customer.Where(cust =>cust.Contact.Where(con=>new{FullName=con.FirstName+" "+con.LastName}.FullName.Contains(searchText)).Any());

var customers = query.AsEnumerable().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This is close to what I need, however, your code is using the Customer parent table and I need the same routine to work on the Customer.Contact child table. I've tried applying your suggestion to the child Contact table but I still did not get any results back from the database.

Comment: here is the code I modified using your suggestion but still no results. .Where(cust => cust.Contact.Select(con => new {FullName = con.FirstName + " " + con.LastName})
                                         .Select(f => f.FullName).Contains(searchText));

Comment: Please use the query as it is I have given, hope it will be working.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't respecting the case of the strings: "John" and "john" are two different people.

```
    IQueryable<Customer> query = dc.Customer
                                   .Where(cust =>
                                   cust.Contact.Select(con => 
                                   con.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant() 
                                   + " " +          
                                   con.LastName.ToUpperInvariant())
                                  .Contains(searchText.ToUpperInvariant()));
```

`ToUpperInvariant()` makes the string culture-insensitive and forces both your returned values and your search text to be case-insensitive by reading them as uppercase.  Don't use lowercase in this way, as that can cause issues when you use more culture-sensitive approaches.   VS 2017 will show a warning if you use lowercase like this and propose going to uppercase to fix it.

Also, remember that whitespace isn't always just empty.  If you are still getting no results and should be, you may need to `.Trim()` at the end of the first and last name strings to drop carriage returns and whitespaces.

Finally, just a note as a suggestion; it's better to split a first name and last name into two separate searches than to combine first and last name, stick a space in it, and then search against the full name.  This prevents surprises caused by you modifying the string before it's digested. For instance, if your input is "John " "Doe" because there's a space in the first name field, your code will create "John  Doe".  When it searches against "John Doe" it will find no records.

You can keep much of what you have with a slightly lazier search:

```
IQueryable<Customer> query = dc.Customer
                                   .Where(cust =>
                                   cust.Contact.Select(con => 
                                   con.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant().Trim()
                                   +                                   
                                   con.LastName.ToUpperInvariant().Trim())                                      
                                     .Contains(searchText.ToUpperInvariant()
                                         .Replace(" ", string.Empty).Trim()));
```

That removes the space, forces it all to uppercase, removes whitespaces, and creates a search key of firstnamelastname...so now you're comparing JOHNDOE (string from the search) to JOHNDOE (input).  It's a little sloppy but does the job in lightweight apps.

Comment: Thanks for the code and explanation. However, I am using linq to sql and .Contains converts to a like statement in sql server which is case in sensitive - all these are hits - joe Joe JOE etc.